# Why is this recursive function 3x faster than iterative one?

Tags: java, recursion

I have a simple recursive function that constructs a binary tree of certain depth.

I thought that iterative version with DFS stack will achieve similar performance, but it is surprisingly 3x slower!

More precisely on my machine the recursive version, for depth of 15, takes ~330_000 ns, while the iterative one with stack takes ~950_000 ns.

Can the surprising performance be attributed to just superior cache locality (which should be obviously better for recursive function).

The code that I used for performance benchmarking:

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        long runs;
        Tree t = null;
        for(runs=0; (System.nanoTime() - startTime)< 3_000_000_000L ; runs++) {
            t = createTree3(15);
        }
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / runs + " ns/call");
    }

    static Tree createTree(int depth) {
        Tree t = new Tree();
        createTreeHlp(t, depth);
        return t;
    }

    static void createTreeHlp(Tree tree, int depth) {
        if (depth == 0)
            tree.init(0, null, null);
        else {
            tree.init(depth, new Tree(), new Tree());
            createTreeHlp(tree.leftChild, depth -1);
            createTreeHlp(tree.rghtChild, depth -1);
        }
    }


    static Tree createTree3(int depth_) {
        TreeStack stack = new TreeStack();
        Tree result = new Tree();
        stack.put(result, depth_);
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            int depth = stack.depth[stack.stack][stack.index];
            Tree tree = stack.tree[stack.stack][stack.index];
            stack.dec();
            if (depth == 0)
                tree.init(0, null, null);
            else {
                tree.init(depth, new Tree(), new Tree());
                stack.put(tree.leftChild, depth -1);
                stack.put(tree.rghtChild, depth -1);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class Tree {
    int payload;
    Tree leftChild;
    Tree rghtChild;

    public Tree init(int payload, Tree leftChild, Tree rghtChild) {
        this.leftChild = leftChild;
        this.rghtChild = rghtChild;
        this.payload = payload;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tree(" +payload+", "+ leftChild + ", " + rghtChild + ")";
    }
}
class TreeStack {

    Tree[][] tree;
    int[][] depth;

    int stack =  1;
    int index = -1;

    TreeStack() {
        this.tree = new Tree[100][];
        this.depth = new int[100][];

        alloc(100_000);
        --stack;
        alloc(0);
    }

    boolean isEmpty() {
        return index == -1;
    }

    void alloc(int size) {
        tree[stack] = new Tree[size];
        depth[stack] = new int[size];
    }

    void inc() {
        if (tree[stack].length == ++index) {
            if (tree[++stack] == null) alloc(2 * index);
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    void dec() {
        if (--index == -1)
            index = tree[--stack].length - 1;
    }

    void put(Tree tree, int depth) {
        inc();
        this.tree[stack][index] = tree;
        this.depth[stack][index] = depth;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you will get some insights [using a profiler](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers)?

Comment: I tried profiling the code with VisualVM, but it only tells me that 70% of self time is spent in the bodies of `createTree1` and `createTree3`. The rest is Tree init. Stack operations are less than 10%.

Comment: Is there any reason you wrote your own stack instead of using `ArrayDeque`? I'm still seeing the iterative slowness with AD, but just curious.

Comment: This is not just recursive vs. iterative. The iterative solution is too complicated and, i think, it uses much time on handling the stack. It would be possible to make a better iterative solution.

Comment: @Donat I would be very interested in a less complicated iterative version, as long as it does not change the order of traversal (DFS).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: because you coded it so.

Long answer: you create a stack, put things in it, get things from it, and do it very complicatedly. Let's do it simply for this case. You want a tree of certain depth that has all children populated, value is the depth and you want the deepest level first. Here's a simple way to do it:

```
static Tree createTree3(int depth_) {
    Tree[] arr = new Tree[1 << depth_];

    int count = 1 << depth_;
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        arr[i] = new Tree().init(0, null, null);

    int d = 1;
    count >>= 1;
    while (count > 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            Tree t = new Tree().init(d, arr[i * 2], arr[i * 2 + 1]);
            arr[i] = t;
        }
        count >>= 1;
        d++;
    }

  return arr[0];
}
```

What it does it first creates the lowest level nodes, of which there are 2^depth of. Then it creates the next level nodes and adds the children. Then the next and the next. No stacks, no recursion, just simple looping.

I benchmarked it by running both 20000 times to depth 14 so there's no calls for getting time or anything, just creating trees. The results on my i7 laptop:

Your recursive takes ~187µs/tree
My iterative takes ~177µs/tree

If I run depth 15 then it's 311 vs 340.

The times change since it's not checking CPU time but system time, things depend on if the JITter does things differently etc etc.

But in short: iterative can easily be made to be as fast as the recursive in this case even with this simple change and I'm sure there's even smarter way of doing it.

Comment: The problem with this approach is it does not traverse the the tree in the same order as the recursive one, so you are comparing two different algorithms.
For that reason alone I cannot accept this answer.

Comment: @FordO. What order should that be? You wanted a DFS and that’s how this one goes. You can also do it the other way if you like, it’s easy to modify

Comment: You do not allocated the tree nodes in the same way the recursive version does.

Comment: Imagine the tree isnt balanced.

Comment: @FordO. Order of allocation doesn’t much matter here. You asked about this specific case, so that’s what I answered. The end result is what matters, otherwise you’ll get identical code which works identically and there’s no question at all. Or you’ll have to be more specific. In the end the answer still is: you wrote a slow implementation.

Comment: I tried to model the iterative version as closely as possible to the recursive one: it traverses and allocates the nodes in very similar manner. Therefore I am interested in implementation that also tries to model the recursive version as closely as possible...